# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end, in HAML using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

Once I replaced "form{:action => "/comments"}" with a "form_tag('/comments')" in the following code:

```
  =form_tag('/comments')
    %fieldset
      %input.comment_input{ :name => "comment[comment]", :size => 60, :type => "text" }
      %input{ :name => "comment[activity_id]", :type => 'hidden', :value => "#{activity.id}" } 
      %button.post_coment_btn{ :type => "submit", :formmethod => "post"} Add Comment
```

I then got the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end
```

. . on line 18, but the file containing the above only has 17 lines.  Am I using the form_tag incorrectly?

<-- Update -->

Using the form_tag do as indicated by @Ben Zhang worked only I actually wanted to go to the 'create' action in the 'comments' controller:

```
=form_tag :action => 'create', :controller => 'comments' do
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one

```
= form_tag :action => '/comments' do
```

Comment: Lost 15 minutes to this one...d'oh!